# Check entered value is number or not

Tags: android, integer

I've tried this snippet, but it doesn't work

```
try 
    {
    Integer.parseInt(enteredID.getText().toString());
    Log.i("enteredID value", "enterdID is numeric!!!!!!!!!!!^^^");
    flag=1;
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    flag=-1;
    Log.i("enteredID value", "enterdID isn't numeric!!!!!!!!!!!^^^");
}
```

take care that it can accept either username or id to check the value,
I don't want it to accept only numbers!!

Answer (score 23):

If boolean value is true then it is number otherwise string value

```
boolean digitsOnly = TextUtils.isDigitsOnly(editText.getText());
```

or for Example

```
String text = edt_email.getText().toString();
            boolean digitsOnly = TextUtils.isDigitsOnly(text);
            if (digitsOnly) {
                 if (text.length() == 0) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "field can't be empty.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                 } else {
                   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "field is int value", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                 }
            }else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Field is string value", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 21):

Use this expression for validate number only

```
String regexStr = "^[0-9]*$";

if(et_number.getText().toString().trim().matches(regexStr))
{
    //write code here for success
}
else{
    // write code for failure
}
```

Comment: This works for me, except I'm trying to allow a decimal also, and when I copy a number like 33.8, it fails... how do I update the regexStr to allow the decimal point also?

Comment: you have to replace this "^[0-9]*$" string with "^[1-9]\d*(\.\d+)?$"

Comment: Work for me. but in android use `"^[1-9]\\d*(\\.\\d+)?$"` Thanks

Answer (score 7):

set EditText proprerty inputType = number it will always take numbers as input

```
android:inputType="number"
```

Comment: thnx,but i wrote a note that i want the user to enter both number and characters,for each different piece of code to be executed

Answer (score 5):

Try with this regular expression :

```
String regex = "-?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?";

if (enteredID.getText().toString().matches(regex))  {
     Log.i("enteredID value", "enterdID is numeric!!!!!!!!!!!^^^");
     flag=1;
 } else {
     flag=-1;
     Log.i("enteredID value", "enterdID isn't numeric!!!!!!!!!!!^^^");
 }
```

Answer (score 5):

Use `TextUtils` class function for that

```
TextUtils.isDigitsOnly("gifg");
```

it will return true if only digits are there and false if any character exists inside string

Answer (score 2):

use this method

```
 boolean isNumber(String string) {
    try {
      int amount = Integer.parseInt(string);
      return true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
      return false;
    }
  }
```

like this :

```
if (isNumber(input)) {
  // string is int
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should never use an exception in this way really. When you expect an exception to be thrown like this you should find an alternative way of handling it.

Try using: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setRawInputType%28int%29

Something like this should do it:

```
editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_SIGNED);
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this:

```
    String text = enteredID.getText().toString();

    if(text.matches("\\w+")){
      //--words--
    }else if (text.matches("\\d+")){
      //--numeric--
    }else {
      //-- something else --
    }
```

You can change the regex to match complex formats.

Answer (score 0):

```
Pattern ptrn = Pattern.compile(regexStr);

if (!ptrn.matcher(et_number.getText().toString().trim()).matches()) {

    //write code here for success

}else{

    //write code here for success

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String text = editText123.getText().toString();
try {
   int num = Integer.parseInt(text);
   Log.i("",num+" is a number");
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
   Log.i("",text+" is not a number");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this function for checking three digit Integer and Float values with two positions after decimal point. If you don't want to limit number of digits, remove the {x,x} from the regular expression.

```
private boolean isNumeric(String string) {
     if(Pattern.matches("\\d{1,3}((\\.\\d{1,2})?)", string))
          return true;
     else
          return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

on the activity simply add inside the  
android:inputType="number"

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
 * If @param digit is null or not any of the numbers - @return false.
 */
static boolean isNumber(String digit) {
    try {
        Double.parseDouble(digit);
    } catch (NullPointerException | NumberFormatException ignored) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Code-only answers are low quality answers.